# Use of the word “penultimate”

Tags: word-usage

Can you use the word *penultimate* to refer to December Thirtieth?

Comment: Related question, [Is “penultimate” commonly used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/is-penultimate-commonly-used) and [Is there a word for the day before the last day of a period, which is measured by days?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75767/is-there-a-word-for-the-day-before-the-last-day-of-a-period-which-is-measured-b/75768#75768). Please make sure you use the search first before posting any question here.

Comment: **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Why would you not be able to?

Answer (score 5):

Penultimate means second to last, so if you're referring to the days in December, the 30th would be the penultimate day in December.

Comment: I'm disappointed, considering the day and all, that you didn't mention "the penultimate day of the [any] year".

Comment: But many people live substantially in the present. For them, a more immediate timespan is more significant than a longer-range one.